# Dog with lint stuck on tooth

Tags: dogs, dental-care

When I was at work my dog destroyed his blanket. He was stuck at through his tooth. I cut the blanket and set him free. However there's a small lint of the blanket in one of his teeth. I'm not able to remove it. I'm wondering if I have to take him to vet or it would be removed naturally.

Comment: My little boy allowed me to open his mouth and I managed to remove the lint. However I'm still curious to know if it would be removed naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the item stuck in your dogs teeth does not pose a potential risk to swallowing or breathing (*or signs of discomfort or bleeding*)... If it does then an emergency vet visit is in order.

If the item stuck in the teeth does not self clear by the next day, then contact the vet for an appointment. Anything pressing against soft tissue like gums can cause injury.